# I try to get data from postgreySQL basis on criteria using grails and groovy but i am facing issue while accesing the list foregin key id

Tags: grails, groovy

**ProductViewerController.groovy**

```
 class ProductViewerController {

    def index(Integer id) { 
  def result=ProductLoader.createCriteria().list {
   eq("product_barcode",id)
  }

  result.each {
   notes->println "${notes}"
  }
  render(view:'index.gsp')  
 }
}
```

**ProductLoader.groovy (Model class)**

> ```
>  class ProductLoader {
>  String store
>  double price
>  String notes
>  static belongsTo =[product_barcode : Product]    
>  static constraints = {
>   store()
>   price()
>   notes()
>
>     }
> }
> ```

i am trying to get data on the basis of foreign key id then get classCastException:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property `product_barcode` needs to be compared with an object type of `Product`

```
def result = ProductLoader.createCriteria().list {
   eq("product_barcode", Product.get(id))
}
```

Or you join the foreign table like

```
def result = ProductLoader.createCriteria().list {
   product_barcode {
       eq("id", id)
   }
}
```